# Laravel | как обратиться к авторизации AJAX-запросом

Tags: ajax, laravel, валидация, auth

На Laravel 5.8.38 выполнил php artisan make:auth.
Хочу зарегистрировать пользователя с помощью AJAX, получая при этом ошибки валидации.
Как это сделать?

---

Обновление:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написать свой контроллер, подключить к api роутам.

Comment: Тогда не присылаются ошибки валидации

Comment: Почему не присылаются? Всё присылается нормально с 422 ошибкой. Но Вы сами их должны обрабатывать на странице. Хотите нормально писать SPA - магии не случится, нужно всё ручками)

Comment: Добавил скрин того, что приходит. По идее должна была прийти ошибка, что поле email обязательно. Я ничего не менял в коде, только добавил в api роут

Comment: Вы заголовок `content-type: application/json` в постмэне выставили?

Comment: После вашего комментария выставил, результат тот же

Comment: Точно в `routes/api.php` добавлен роут? Если да, то явно проблема веб-сервера. Потому что ссылки api с типом json уж точно не возвращают главную страницу. Да и без типа на login должно перекинуть...

Comment: Вот -   Route::post('register','Auth\RegisterController@register');
Ну ладно, покопаюсь в интернете еще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные должны передаваться в body. В постман запросе вы имеете данную вкладку

В ней можно выбрать либо form-data или raw со значением json вместо text

Comment: Как и через вкладку body/form-data так и через params данные правильно доходят, но и так, и так, ошибки валидации все равно не приходят... :(

Comment: тогда добавь заголовок Accept application/json

Comment: Сработало, прям вот спасибо человеческое